# How to change the position of module of magento cart?

Tags: php, magento, module, themes, cart

How i change the position of module of magento cart (top/button...left/Right)??

Answer (score 3):

The quick and dirty way is to change the checkout.xml layout file.

open

```
frontend/default/default/layout/checkout.xml
```

find the line that says

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
        ............................
    </block>
</reference>
```

and change reference name to left,top,root,content etc... This determines the position of the cart in the layout

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
        ............................
    </block>
</reference>
```

You may have to clear your cache or delete /var/cache to see your changes.

The proper way to this would be to override the checkout Module , look at the magento wiki to learn more about overriding modules.